# Function stops without any logs in firebase (sometimes works well.. sometimes partly) - confused

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can you please share your thoughts or experience why this can happen:
I have a folder on firebase cloud with a bunch of images (jpeg, png). It can contain from 2 to 40+ files. After uploading the files from the client is complete, a request is sent to the firebase initiating resizing function of these new images.
Resizing should work as:

- uploading every file to tmpFilePath (*for (const file of files)* loop is used)
- resizing the files in tmpFilePath (I tried *spawn* and *sharp*, and *sharp* seems to be more stable)
- downloading the resized file back to the folder.

The problem is that the function doesn't work from time to time. Sometimes it stops at the step of downloading to tmpFilePath with no logs. After re-initiating, it can proceed a couple of files and stop again. Sometimes it works well. I thought the file size matters, but again, the same folder with the same files can work ok after several initiations.. Confused. Is it specific to firebase functions?

This is a short version of the code:

```
for (const file of files)  {

console.log(`${file} before downloading to tempFolder`)   


    await destBucket.file(filePath).download({
                destination: tmpFilePath
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                .then(() => {

console.log(`${file} before sharp`)

    return sharp (tmpFilePath, { failOnError: false }) 
                      .resize(resizedW, resizedH)
                      .toFile (afterSharpPath) 
                      .then(() => {

console.log(`${file} before uploading back`)  

    return destBucket.upload(afterSharpPath, { 
                    destination: filePath,
                    contentType: orType,
                    metadata: {metadata: newMetadata},
                    bucket: bucket,
                    })
    
    } } }
```

Anyone have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: Please edit the question to share your debugging information.  That should include logging you add to trace what's happening, as well as error messages that indication the problem.  Please also share the [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) function code that anyone can use to reproduce the isue.

Comment: hi Doug. I added several lines of console.log() after every step in the loop. The last log I can see when the function fails is `${file} before downloading to tempFolder`. It just stops (sometimes) and doesn't throw any error (as I see it). The complete function is quite complicated with many checks of the metadata, dimensions, etc... the point is that it works in, let's say, 50% of cases. And as I mentioned, when it fails, the last log is the one before downloading to temp folder

Comment: Could you please provide enough information to reproduce the issue? Here is a good document to understand what's expected in order to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: guys, just some update -- I took this function image resizing) from firebase and it is happening on the other server now. It works just fine there. I should have done it way before. Firebase function is a beast which quite difficult to deal with...